# How to authenticate user on logout page

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security, spring-webflow, cas

I'm very new to cas server and now I'm just encountered another issue. When the user clicks on logout button, the application redirects to

> https://localhost:8443/cas/logout

And I want to show the user a message upon successful logout and the remaining parts of that page is same as login page, I mean there are inputs for getting username and password and a submit button.

My configurations in spring-security.xml file are somethings like:

```
<logout logout-url="/logout" delete-cookies="true"
        invalidate-session="true"
        logout-success-url="https://${cas.server.host}/cas/logout?service=https://${cas.service.host}/MyApp1/" />
```

```
<b:bean id="requestSingleLogoutFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter"
    p:filterProcessesUrl="/logout">
    <b:constructor-arg value="https://${cas.server.host}/cas/logout" />
    <b:constructor-arg>
        <b:bean
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler" />
    </b:constructor-arg>
</b:bean>
```

So what should I do?

Comment: Your `login.jsp` can act for both **login** as well as **logout** , In `login.jsp` check for **requestParameter** having `logout message` if it exist show it else leave it .

Comment: that's true, but the main problem is, whenever the user enters username and password and hit submit button, the exception we got is:org.springframework.webflow.definition.registry.NoSuchFlowDefinitionException: No flow definition 'logout' found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you gotta do is to add following changes to your spring-security.xml

```
<b:bean id="requestSingleLogoutFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter"
    p:filterProcessesUrl="/logout">
    <b:constructor-arg value="https://${cas.server.host}/cas/logout?service=https://${cas.service.host}/MyApp1/j_spring_cas_security_check" />
    <b:constructor-arg>
        <b:bean
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler" />
    </b:constructor-arg>
</b:bean>
```

And uncomment

> cas.logout.followServiceRedirects=true

In cas.properties file from cas server application.

I hope this would help.

Regards.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's all I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Someting similar to this will help you out

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${empty param.name}">// name is the Request Parameter
        Please enter your name.
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        Hello <b><c:out value="${param.name}" /></b>!
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Send Request like this on click of logout

> https://localhost:8443/cas/login.jsp?logout=Thanks for Visiting Cas !!!